# mui/material 5.14 - autocomplet with different Options structure

Tags: next.js, material-ui, formik

so i am using MUI 5.14 with Formik 2.4

formik initial values are setup as follows

```
  initialValues: { invoice_type: {} }
```

now for the MUI5 options structure

```
invoiceTypes = [{label: "option 1", id:"1"}, {label: "option 2", id:"2"}]
```

```
  <CustomAutoComplete
                  id="invoice_type"
                  name="invoice_type"
                  label="Invoice Type"
                  options={invoiceTypes}
                  value={formik.values.invoice_type.id} //
                  renderOption={(props, option) => (
                    <li {...props} key={option.id}>
                      {option.label}
                    </li>
                  )}
                  onChange={(_, val) => {
                    formik.setFieldValue("invoice_type", val.id);
                  }}
                  error={
                    formik.touched.invoice_type &&
                    Boolean(formik.errors.invoice_type)
                  }
                  helperText={
                    formik.touched.invoice_type && formik.errors.invoice_type
                  }
                />
```

the codes works fine and i am able to get the id of the selection option. for e.g. if i select option 2 in the autocomplete then the value during form submission is 2.

when i reset the formik form the values goes back to what is present in the initialValues oject.

but the selected text in the mui autocomplete is still displayed.

nothing seems to be working, if the pass just an array as options in the autocomplete then invoiceTypes = [1,2,3] the form resets as expected -> but when an array of object is passed as options it doesnt reset.

how do i fix this ?